# Lucene boosting not working

Tags: c#, full-text-search, lucene.net

I'm indexing a document and setting the boost as follows:

```
document.SetBoost(5f);
```

because I want certain documents to appear before. For example, I want more recent news to show first.

When I do the search, like this:

```
var parser = new QueryParserEx(Version.LUCENE_29, "contents", analyzer);
parser.SetDefaultOperator(QueryParser.Operator.AND);
parser.SetMultiTermRewriteMethod(MultiTermQuery.SCORING_BOOLEAN_QUERY_REWRITE);

Query query;
query = parser.Parse("text*");
```

The query gets parsed as a `WildcardQuery` and internally it's using this:

```
{Lucene.Net.Search.MultiTermQuery.AnonymousClassConstantScoreAutoRewrite}
```

Not sure why it's still using a Constant Score rewriter.  Can someone explain?

I also believe I cannot use at search-time boosting as I don't need to boost certain terms, but certain documents (eg, most recent news appear first).

PS: This is **not** a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12789063/lucene-net-setboost-on-field-is-not-affecting-results).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind. I was using a custom implementation of the `QueryParser` that had the method `NewTermQuery` overwritten.

Something like this:

```
protected override Query NewTermQuery(Term term)
{
    var field = term.Field();
    var text = term.Text() ?? "";
    if (field == "contents" &&
        text.Length >= 3 &&
        text.IndexOfAny(new[] { '*', '?' }) < 0)
    {
        var wq = new WildcardQuery(new Term(field, text + "*"));
        return wq;
    }
    return base.NewTermQuery(term);
}
```

And the `WildcardQuery` was not taking that configuration. All I had to do is call `wq.SetMultiTermRewriteMethod(MultiTermQuery.SCORING_BOOLEAN_QUERY_REWRITE);` inside that `if`.